# How to return a promise in redux actions - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, promise

I am trying to get location from redux when needed. After redux save the location to the state i need to return a promise since i need that data in my screen.

here are my actions, reducers, store, and how i use them.

`LocationRedux.tsx`

```
import * as Type from './LocationReduxTypes';
const initialState: Type.LocationState = {
    location: undefined,
};
const LocationRedux = (
    state = initialState,
    action: Type.LocationActionTypes,
): Type.LocationState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Type.SET_LOCATION:
            return { ...state, location: action.location };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export { LocationRedux as default };
```

`LocationReduxActions.tsx` - here i need to return a promise that when i use this method, i need to know location is resolved.

```
import * as Type from './LocationReduxTypes';
import Store from '~/Redux/Store';

import { GeolocationResponse } from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

class LocationReduxActions {
    public static SetLocation(location: GeolocationResponse) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(
                Store.instance.dispatch({
                    type: Type.SET_LOCATION,
                    location,
                }),
            );
            reject(
                console.log('rejected'),
            );
        });

    }
}

export { LocationReduxActions as default };
```

`LocationReduxType.tsx`

```
import { MenuItemType } from '~/Helpers/Menu';
import { GeolocationResponse } from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

export const SET_LOCATION = 'SET_LOCATION';

interface SetLocationAction {
    type: typeof SET_LOCATION;
    location?: GeolocationResponse;
}

export interface LocationState {
    location?: GeolocationResponse;
}
export type LocationActionTypes = SetLocationAction;
```

and this is how i am trying to use this action.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.props.location) {
            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(location => {
                LocationReduxActions.SetLocation(location)
                .then(() => { // debugger never hit this then method.
                    this._load();
                });
            }, () => { // error handling.
                this._load();
            });
        } else { 
            this._load(); 
        }
    }
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the then is called, you're indeed returning a Promise from `SetLocation`, and resolving it.

Also, note that `dispatch` is synchronous, so you don't need a promise : the store is updated once it has been called.

By the way, if you want to update your UI based on what's in the store, a simpler and common approach is `react-redux`.